# Asymptotic analysis : Theory

Tags: asymptotics

how do you prove that when the limit of n approaches towards positive infinity while n^2/(log n)! We tried to used Stirling theorem but this may not work due to the fact that it may or may not exist on all intervals.

Comment: Are you sure this is $(\log n)!$ and not $\log(n!)$ ?

Comment: yes, I am 100% for sure that it is (log n)!. I'm trying to show that n^2 is a member of O((log n)!)

Comment: Is $n$ assumed to be a power of $2$? Otherwise, $\log_2 n$ is not an integer (you can use the $\Gamma$ function instead, in this case, but the factorial as written would not be defined.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ is a power of $2$, write $n=2^k$ and apply Stirling's approximation to $k!$ to show that
$$\begin{align}
\frac{n^2}{\log^2 n} &= \frac{2^{2k}}{k!} \sim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^{2k}}{\sqrt{2\pi k}\left(\frac{k}{e}\right)^k}
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi k}}\cdot \frac{2^{(2+\log e)k}}{2^{k\log k}} =
2^{- k\log k + (2+\log e)k - \frac{1}{2}\log k + O(1) }  \\ &= 2^{-k\log k + o(k\log k)}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0.
\end{align}$$

If $n$ is not a power of two, then $(\log n)!$ should be interpreted as $\Gamma(\log n+1)$. Then use $\Gamma(\log n+1) \geq \Gamma(\lceil \log n \rceil)$ (the $\Gamma$ function is increasing) and do the above for $k = \lceil \log n \rceil$.

Comment: Just curious, and not that it changes the development, but why have you assumed base $2$ for the logarithm?

Comment: Oh, yes. CS perspective...

Comment: What does "CS" mean?

Comment: (Computer Science)

Comment: so for 2^(−klogk+o(klogk)), how do we know that o(klogk) approaches zero?

Comment: $- k\log k + o(k\log k) \xrightarrow[k\to\infty]{} -\infty$, since the first term dominates and goes to $-\infty$. So $2^{- k\log k + o(k\log k)} \xrightarrow[k\to\infty]{} "2^{-\infty}" = 0$.